# How to deal with non-Send futures in a Tokio spawn context?

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

[Tokio's spawn](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/fn.spawn.html) can only work with a `Send` future. This makes the following code invalid:

```rust
async fn async_foo(v: i32) {}

async fn async_computation() -> Result<i32, Box<dyn std::error::Error>> {
    Ok(1)
}

async fn async_start() {
    match async_computation().await {
        Ok(v) => async_foo(v).await,
        _ => unimplemented!(),
    };
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    tokio::spawn(async move {
        async_start().await;
    });
}
```

The error is:

```
future cannot be sent between threads safely
the trait `Send` is not implemented for `dyn std::error::Error`
```

If I understand correctly: because `async_foo(v).await` might yield, Rust internally have to save all the context which might be on a different thread - hence the result of `async_computation().await` must be `Send` - which `dyn std::error::Error` is not.

This could be mitigated **if** the non-`Send` type can be dropped before the `.await`, such as:

```rust
async fn async_start() {
    let result;
    match async_computation().await {
        Ok(v) => result = v,
        _ => return,
    };

    async_foo(result).await;
}
```

However once another `.await` is needed before the non-`Send` type is dropped, the workarounds are more and more awkward.

What a is a good practice for this - especially when the non-`Send` type is for generic error handling (the `Box<dyn std::error::Error>`)? Is there a better type for errors that common IO ops implements (async or not) in Rust? Or there is a better way to group nested async calls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most errors are `Send` so you can just change the return type to:

```rs
Box<dyn std::error::Error + Send>
```

It's also common to have `+ Sync`.